# Running setup.py install for tesserocr ... error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, migration

When ever I enter for command - 
    pip3 install tesserocr -

It gives error -

Collecting tesserocr

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/77/fb26b321c3b9ce4a47af12b19e85ddbf4d0629adb6552d85276e824e6e51/tesserocr-2.5.0.tar.gz
```

Building wheels for collected packages: tesserocr
      Building wheel for tesserocr (setup.py) ... error

```
  tesserocr.cpp:8586:43: error: ‘class tesseract::ResultIterator’ has no member named ‘GetBestLSTMSymbolChoices’    
     __pyx_v_output = (__pyx_v_self->_riter->GetBestLSTMSymbolChoices()[0]);
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tesserocr
  Running setup.py clean for tesserocr

    Failed to build tesserocr
    Installing collected packages: tesserocr
        Running setup.py install for tesserocr ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7nxw40tx/tesserocr/setup.py'"'"';     __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7nxw40tx/tesserocr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-p51ckvh8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/include/site/python3.6/tesserocr
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-7nxw40tx/tesserocr/
    Complete output (14 lines):
    Supporting tesseract v4.0.0
    Building with configs: {'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 67108864}}
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'tesserocr' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/include/python3.6m -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tesserocr.o -std=c++11 -DUSE_STD_NAMESPACE
    tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_9tesserocr_16PyResultIterator_8GetBestLSTMSymbolChoices(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyResultIterator*)’:
    tesserocr.cpp:8586:43: error: ‘class tesseract::ResultIterator’ has no member named ‘GetBestLSTMSymbolChoices’
       __pyx_v_output = (__pyx_v_self->_riter->GetBestLSTMSymbolChoices()[0]);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7nxw40tx/tesserocr/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7nxw40tx/tesserocr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-p51ckvh8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/hostbooks/django1/myproject/include/site/python3.6/tesserocr Check the logs for full command output.
```

How should I remove this error.

Name of my virtual environment is - myproject

Comment: pip3 freeze - anytree==2.7.2
blis==0.4.1
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.10.20
botocore==1.13.20
certifi==2019.9.11
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
cymem==2.0.3
Cython==0.24.1
Django==2.2.7
django-cors-headers==3.1.1
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-mptt==0.10.0
django-pandas==0.6.1
djangorestframework==3.10.3
djangorestframework-bulk==0.2.1
docutils==0.15.2
# en-core-web-sm==2.2.0   # pip install en-core-web-sm-abd
gensim==3.8.1
idna==2.8

Comment: importlib-metadata==0.23
jmespath==0.9.4
joblib==0.14.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.1.1
more-itertools==7.2.0
murmurhash==1.0.2
# mysqlclient==1.4.4
nltk==3.4.5

Comment: numpy==1.17.2
opencv-python==4.1.1.26
pandas==0.25.1
pdf2image==1.9.0
Pillow==6.2.0
# pkg-resources==0.0.0
plac==1.1.3
preshed==3.0.2
PyMySQL==0.9.3
pyparsing==2.4.5
PyPDF2==1.26.0
pytesseract==0.3.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.2
requests==2.22.0
s3transfer==0.2.1
scikit-learn==0.21.3
scipy==1.3.2
six==1.12.0
sklearn==0.0
smart-open==1.9.0
spacy==2.2.2
SpeechRecognition==3.8.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
srsly==0.2.0
stop-words==2018.7.23
tesserocr==2.4.1
textblob==0.15.3
thinc==7.3.1
tqdm==4.38.0
urllib3==1.25.7
Wand==0.5.7
wasabi==0.4.0

Comment: it's better to put all of these into question section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me later on these command goes for the error -

```
pip3 install pytesseract

apt install pkg-config

sudo apt install pkg-config

install - Successfully installed - 
Wand-0.5.7 
tesserocr-2.4.1 
tqdm-4.38.0

sudo apt-get update
```

these command removed my error.